# PHP populated field returns 0 even if populated

Tags: php

I have a MySQL row I get data from by doing this:

```
...['immobile' => $dati_immobile->row(),]...
```

I then have a table and I pass every field inside a function, this is the function code:

```
public function brochurefield($field, $label, $checkbox = false)
{
    if($field == 0){
        return '<tr><td>'.$label.' Is zero</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

When I echo this function with a text field taken from the MySQL it returns 0:

```
//This returns "Accessori Bagno Is zero"
<?= $this->ui_model->brochurefield($immobile->arredo_bagno, "Accessori Bagno") ?>

//This returns "termo arredo" (text from DB)
<tr><td><?= $immobile->arredo_bagno ?></td></tr>
```

It basically reads the field to be `0` instead of "termo arredo".
While if I check the field on `$field == "0"` (string) and `$field == ''` (empty string) the result is false.

The result is true only when I check it against a `0` (int) value.

The problem happens only on string values, while on int values I get the expected results (`brochurefield(32,"test")` returns correctly the number 32).

I use PHP `7.1.1`

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't see any interaction with MySQL in that code. You only write to an HTML 'table', which is shown to the user, but that will in no way save data in MySQL.

Comment: The first line of the post says I get a row from a MySQL table, the rest is all PHP. If I `print_r($immobile)` I have all fields I expect with their respective contents

Comment: @Mr.Web it is quite irrelevant where the data comes from. This is a PHP question, not a MySQL question. That said, which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @GolezTrol and Bart. Sorry, I edited to state PHP and not MySQL

Comment: @BartFriederichs 7.1.1

Comment: You are passing `$immobile->arredo_bagno` into the function where the value from database is `termo arredo` which is string and you are comparing it with numbers. that's the issue?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra I'm passing `$immobile->arredo_bagno`into the function (and other field as well, ints, string and texts) and while it works fine with ints, if I check the field `if($field == 0)` it returns true even if is not (`$immobile->arredo_bagno` is  a field with text in it)

Comment: I can't read the first line properly, because it's incomplete, but it seems you're setting a property or array key: `['immobile' => $dati_immobile->row(),]`. Doing that will not automatically populate `$immobile`. Please try to put the relevant parts of the code in the question. That includes the part between the last line that worked and the first line that doesn't. It's suprisingly hard for us to debug code that you didn't share.. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your if condition like.

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

This means that:

```
("test" == 0) === true
("1test" == 0) === false


if ($field == "" || $field == "0" || (is_numeric($field) && $field == 0)) {
```

For more reference you can visit [PHP manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Wow, totally new for me. Thanks a lot!!